# NodeJS exit code is shifted 8 bits to the left

Tags: c, node.js, return-value

I have two programs, program 'a' written in C and program 'b' written in NodeJS. I execute program 'b' from program 'a' like this:

```
int retVal = system("node /path/to/progB.js");
printf("%d",retVal);
```

And my program 'b' looks something like this:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        if (body === 'something') {
            process.exitCode = 0;
        } else if (body === 'something else') {
            process.exitCode = 1;
        } else {
            process.exitCode = 2;
        }

    } else {
        console.log("ERR" + body + response);
        process.exitCode = 3;
    }
});
```

back in program 'a' return values are either `0`, `256`, `512` or `768`. Which in binary is: `0000 0000 0000`, `0001 0000 0000`, `0010 0000 0000`, `0011 0000 0000`. By inspecting these numbers I can clearly see that my return values are bits  8 and 9, therefore my return value is shifted 8 bits to the left. But why?

System is Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and compiler is gcc version 6.3.0

Comment: System(s) you are running on, and compiler versions you are using may be relevant. Please [edit] and add that information.

Comment: Please quote the documenation of the return values in your environment, highlighting the part which makes you think that what you observe is incorrect.

Comment: @user694733 edited

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the macros `WIFEXITED`, `WEXITSTATUS` and friends to interpret the result of `system`.  See the man page of wait(2) for more details about the macros.